# Eclipse's "Open Project" takes forever

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse with a few projects in it.  It has been running fine.

But all of a sudden, an "Open Project" operation took forever to finish.  At that point I think I might have lost my patience so I cancelled the operation.  That appeared to have cancel that operation, but then later when I wanted to do anything (such as opening a file, or even shutting down Eclipse), an operation "Open Project (Cancel Requested)" was triggered, and it was sitting there forever again.  I am showing an screenshot below:

[image]

How can I bail out?

I have looked at the log file `...\workspace\.metadata\.log`

The only messages there were from two days ago (today is 2015-12-25).  I think they are not related:

```
!ENTRY com.google.gdt.eclipse.core 2 0 2016-12-23 16:49:50.092
!MESSAGE Unable to connect to https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.9/compositeArtifacts.xml.

!ENTRY com.google.appengine.eclipse.wtp.maven 1 0 2016-12-23 16:50:21.418
!MESSAGE GaeProjectConfigurator.getBuildParticipant invoked

!ENTRY com.google.appengine.eclipse.wtp.maven 1 0 2016-12-23 17:15:15.126
!MESSAGE GaeProjectConfigurator.getBuildParticipant invoked

!ENTRY com.google.appengine.eclipse.wtp.maven 1 0 2016-12-23 17:15:21.527
!MESSAGE GaeProjectConfigurator.getBuildParticipant invoked

!ENTRY com.google.appengine.eclipse.wtp.maven 1 0 2016-12-23 17:15:34.439
!MESSAGE GaeProjectConfigurator.getBuildParticipant invoked
```

Comment: I have the same problem whenever I want to cancel an svn update

Comment: Try removing the `.project`, `.settings` and `.classpath` and then import again.

Comment: Thanks!  Will try it next time if I see the problem again.  Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  I bailed out by killing the Eclipse process (brought up Windows Task Manager, located the Eclipse process, and then clicked on `End Process`).

Upon the next restart of Eclipse, I seems to have lost some states of my workspace (opened files, working set configuration, etc), but any files that I have saved to disk appear to remain intact.  Good.  I saw these message in the log file.  Other than these, every thing seems to have work fine (and now I can close and open the project without issues)

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core 4 4 2016-12-25 10:03:11.847
!MESSAGE A workspace crash was detected. The previous session did not exit normally. Not using saved taglib indexes.

!ENTRY com.google.appengine.eclipse.wtp.maven 1 0 2016-12-25 10:03:18.201
!MESSAGE GaeProjectConfigurator.getBuildParticipant invoked
```